# where to set the max lifetime of kafka message in a broker?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

where to set the max `lifetime` of `kafka` message in a `broker`? what is the default value?

If I use Spark streaming with the combination of Kafka, is there any difference in this settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the retention period(lifetime) of the kafka topic in the **`server.properties`** file of the broker using the below command:

```
# The below configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log as long as the remaining
# segments don't drop below log.retention.bytes.
log.retention.bytes=1073741824
```